# Spring Data REST: Return One-To-Many-To-One as Many-To-Many relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to build a simple HATEOAS API with Spring Boot and Spring Data REST.

Thus, I have created 2 different entities A and B. There is a Many-To-Many relation between both. Because the relation needs 2 more properties, I added a new relation R with these properties.

For the API, only A and B should be visible, R is only internal and has no repository. I'd like to represent A with a link to a collection of B.

It should be possible to create A, create B, link A to B or B to A without providing and returning the internal properties of R.

I guess it's a design problem?

**Possible solutions:**

I tried to create a custom method findByR_Bid() but I cant provide the own id to this method, so "/a/b" is not possible, it's always "/a/search/...".

Next, I've added a custom link with ResponseEntities.linkToCollection(B.class), but this will represent a link to "/b" without a reference to A's own id.

Next, I have implemented a method in A to return List from R. But this list is included internally as property instead of creating a Link.

**A bit code:**

```java
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
  private List<R> r;

  // getters
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
  private List<R> r;

  // getters
}

@Entity
public class R {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private A a;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private B b;

  // internal properties

  @JsonIgnore
  private String foo;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String bar;

  // getters
}
```

For the JSON response I want to have something like this:

GET /a/1

```
"_links" : {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/a/1"
    },
    "a": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/a/1"
    },
    "bs": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/a/1/b{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky, but not impossible!

You can add B to A with a many-to-many relationship (and vica versa) using the same table:

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
  private List<R> r;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "table_r", inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id") })
  private list<B> b;

  // getters
}
```

This way you force hibernate to use the same table for the man-to-many relationship which supports the R entity. Spring Data Rest will also map this many-to-many relationship to the endpoints, so `/a/1/bs` will work.

However accessing the extra properties of the relationship will be still tricky. (you need to use the /search endpoints.)

An other solution if you create a composite key for R (from A+B) instead of standard id. (Which is actually already exists, because the support table for a many-to-many relationship *has* a composite key based on a_id+b_id) 
If you create a converter for the composite key then you can access the relationship properties like:
`/R/23-34` (Relationship between a-23 and b-34)

It's not too nice but works.

Comment: Nice idea using the @JoinTable annotation. I will give this a try. Thanks!